# Generating a link from other columns in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: vb.net, webforms, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid, and it contains three columns which have UniqueName of OrderNo, SendToAddress, and ResendLink.

I would like to have a hyperlink column that calls a JavaScript function when clicked, passing values from the row the hyperlink is in as parameters to the function.

The following code works, but only once on the page.  Subsequent refreshes and the method throws an exception (itemData is null).  *Note: sSearchResults is a POCO used as a data transfer object to return column data.*

```
    Protected Sub dg2_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles dg2.ItemCreated
    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        ' Setup the Resend Link
        Dim item As GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)
        Dim itemData As sSearchResults = CType(item.DataItem, sSearchResults)
        Dim resendLink As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ResendLink"), HyperLink)
        resendLink.Attributes("href") = "javascript:void(0);"
        resendLink.Attributes("onclick") = [String].Format("return ShowResendForm('{0}','{1}');",
                                                           itemData.OrderNo,
                                                           itemData.SendToAddress)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have a suspicion that the above code would work reliably if I moved it to the ItemDataBound event on the grid and set EnableViewState to false.  I haven't tried it yet and I'd prefer not doing that.

**What is the proper way to fetch row data column strings to populate another column like this using RadGrid?**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by, instead, specifying all of the columns that I need to access programmatically from the `ItemCreated` method as `DataKeyNames` in the ASPX.

Then, in the `ItemCreated` event handler, I could access the values like so:

```
e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("OrderNo")
```